# Mobile: Suggested Dual-Action for settings

Tags: mobile, settings

We currently have the problem of having a 'setting' needing to perform 3 different actions. See below:

[image: Dual Action Setting]

The circled setting needs to perform these 3 actions.
(A)The user needs to quickly toggle the setting on/off
(B)The user needs to be able to click the arrow to refine this setting (ie: turn Facebook and/or Twitter off or on)
(C)The user needs to see what their current settings are set for (ie: they need to see whether they have facebook or twitter turned on or off)

What are some ways to solve this problem? Whether it be getting away from the native elements of the device, or whether it be adding a step, etc.

Comment: What OS is this for? iOS/Android or both? The wireframe shows a back button (generally iOS) along with a device back button (like on an Android).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason this has to be set-up using a single line?  While it's nice to minimize on-screen complexity, this seems like it adds additional steps for **many** user cases.

I like how Instagram and RunKeeper handle this... that is to say, have a line for each setting.

[image: Instagram Sharing] [image: RunKeeper Sharing]

Note that my RunKeeper app only shows Facebook because that's the only service I've set-up. That's why I MUCH prefer the Instagram approach because it lists all services that I can share to, and if I haven't set up a given service yet, I can easily hit "configure" without breaking my flow.  Sharing settings can later be modified from the app's settings screen:

[image: Instagram Settings]

One thing that I would like to see from Instagram is an option to "default-on" a service (preferably in the settings pane), so if I always want to share my Instagram photos to Facebook, I wouldn't have to manually flick the switch for every photo (right now, the default is always off).  Alternatively, remembering my last choice (on or off) per service would work for me, too.

I'd strongly recommend you **check out as many comparable apps as you can**, and **test, test, test** to make sure you're not making a flow unduly cumbersome for your users.